# Is the source of Docker's COPY <SRC> <DEST> always relative to the build context?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a bunch of build scripts in my Dockerfile's build context and would like to use the entire context inside the build. Is this the correct way to copy the build context into the new container?

```
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
```

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way. Beware that it'll copy the `Dockerfile` as well. Use [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) to avoid that

Comment: Thanks, OK by me, the Dockerfile is small. Sometimes it might contain secrets?

Comment: Your Dockerfile should not contain secrets. Use build arguments and environment variables to pass secrets at build stage or at runtime respectively.